# Java window lagging on Ubuntu but not windows when code isn't lagging

Tags: java, swing

**EDIT**: this bug only happens when I run my game on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop. When I run it on the Windows school computers it works fine.

the window lags when running normally, but stops lagging while I resize the window with my mouse

I'm trying to make a simple game in java, however when ever I run it, it lags like crazy, I've looked over the code, and done some checks with System.out.println and System.currentTimeMillis and the code runs in much less than a millisecond, so that's not the problem.

The program stops when I drag to resize the window and constantly change the size of the window (presumably forcing a screen redraw), it has nice smooth animation when I do this.

When my program is running, it starts of with smooth animation, then about 1 second later it goes to about 2 FPS, then another second later to goes to 1 FPS, then about 0.5FPS and stays there until I force a repaint by resizing the window

my code is:

```
public class WindowSetup extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6486212988269469205L;
static JFrame frame;
static JPanel panel;
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    GameClass.draw(g);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new JFrame("Evolver");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    panel = new WindowSetup();
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    GameClass.init();
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GameClass.tick();
            panel.repaint();
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(50,al); // lower numbers here make it run faster, but it still ends up slowing down to 1FPS
    timer.start();
}
}
```

My GameClass:

```
public class GameClass {
static Random random;
static ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
static Wall wall;
static void init(){
    random = new Random();
    wall=new Wall();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        enemies.add(new Enemy(random.nextInt(200)+100,random.nextInt(200)+100,10,10,(float) (random.nextFloat()*(Math.PI*2)),1));
    }
}
static void tick(){
    for(Enemy d:enemies){
        d.tick();
    }
}
static void draw(Graphics g){
    for(Enemy d:enemies){
        d.draw(g);
    }
    wall.draw(g);
}
}
```

Enemy Class:

```
public class Enemy {
float x;
float y;
float width;
float height;
float direction;
float speed;

public Enemy(float x, float y, float width, float height, float direction, float speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.speed = speed;
}

public void tick() {
    direction += 0.01;
    if (!(GameClass.wall.collides((int) (x + (Math.cos(direction) * speed)), (int) (y + (Math.sin(direction) * speed)),(int)width,(int)height))) {
        x += Math.cos(direction) * speed;
        y += Math.sin(direction) * speed;
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect((int) x, (int) y, (int) width, (int) height);
}
}
```

Wall code:

```
public class Wall {
ArrayList<Rectangle> rectlist = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

public Wall() {
    // create list of walls here
    rectlist.add(new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 400));
    rectlist.add(new Rectangle(410,10,50,400));
    rectlist.add(new Rectangle(60,10,350,50));
    rectlist.add(new Rectangle(60,360,350,50));
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    for (Rectangle d : rectlist) {
        g.drawRect(d.x, d.y, d.width, d.height);
    }
}
public boolean collides(int x,int y,int width,int height){
    for(Rectangle d:rectlist){
        if(d.intersects(x, y, width, height)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Can we see the contents of your `GameClass`? If it gets _slower over time_, there's a good chance you're not cleaning up where you should be.

Comment: It's really basic moving code, I've added my GameClass and Enemy. GameClass.wall.collides() is just a basic rectangle collision checker, it definitely doesn't make lag.

Comment: Resizing the frame invokes `repaint()` as you drag, adding to those queued by the `Timer`.

Comment: Would you please post the Wall class code? I'm trying to debug it on eclipse

Comment: Is the program logic also slowing down to 0.5 ticks per second, or is it only the graphics?

Comment: Have you tried pluging a profiler on your running game? The most low tech one is probably jvisualvm, where you can still see time spent per method, which might give you some idea...

Comment: it's only the graphics that are slowing down, the logic of the code and the drawing code is running in less than a millisecond. As for using a profiler, I've never used one before.

Comment: it seems to be a problem only when I run it on my linux Ubuntu, but not when I run it on the Windows school computers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a problem with linux's graphics scheduling meaning it gets slower and slower for some reason. The solution to this is using Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync() after you do panel.repaint(), this stops the slowdown.

This function doesn't seem to help anything on other OSes, but it does take up precious CPU cycles (quite a lot of them, actually), so use System.getProperty("os.name") to determine if you need to use it.

Comment: Since you solved your problem, please accept your own answer to close the question.

Comment: It won't let me do it for 2 more days

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I guess you can 'simulate' the resize behavior by adding `setVisible(false)` and `setVisible(true)` around your action listener:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        panel.setVisible(false);
        GameClass.tick();
        panel.repaint();
        panel.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: DO NOT DO! repeat: DO NOT DO! this froze my entire computer, I'm having to use a school computer while mine unfreezes

Comment: wow, can you post the specs of your computer? Its really weird that it would freeze because of this.

Comment: this code is being called 100 times per second, remember. it's an intel core i5-3230m CPU @ 2.60GHz x 4. I have 8 GB of RAM and 1TB of disk space. my laptop is 1 year old and runs off ubuntu 14.04

Comment: whoops, thought it said frame.setVisible, not panel.setVisible. frame.setVisible freezes my computer, panel.setVisible does nothing visibly and doesn't help.

Comment: whew, thank god, i'd feel really bad if my advice actually crashed your computer