# Bouncing ball. Ball is laggy. repaint() too slow

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener, actionevent

I try to do my first graphical program in java - bouncing ball. Actually it should be brick breaker according to tutorial. But for now it is bouncing ball. The ball should bounce from the frames of the window. So far I programmed it. The issue is that the ball is laggy, it does not move fluently at all. **If I press and hold a keyboard key the ball moves fluently**. Firstly I though it might by problem with my graphical card and linux system(AMD Ryzen 5 integrated graphic, Ubuntu 20.04)? But why it works correctly when I press and hold a keyboard button. Any ideas?

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame obj=new JFrame();
    Gameplay gamePlay = new Gameplay();
    obj.setBounds(10,10,700,600);
    obj.setTitle("Breakout Ball");
    obj.setResizable(false);
    obj.setVisible(true);
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(obj.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.add(gamePlay);
    }
}


package com.company;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.swing.*;


public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private boolean play=false;


    private int totalBrics=21;

    private Timer timer;
    private int delay=8;

    private int playerX=310;

    private int ballposX=120;
    private int ballposY=350;
    private int ballXdir=-1;
    private int ballYdir=-2;

    public Gameplay(){
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        timer=new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        //background
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(1,1,692,592);

        //borders
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(0,0,3,592);
        g.fillRect(0,0,692,3);
        g.fillRect(691,0,3,592);

        // paddle
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(playerX, 550,100,8);

        //ball
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(ballposX, ballposY,20,20);

        //g.dispose();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) {
        //timer.start();
        play=true;
        if (play){
            if(new Rectangle(ballposX, ballposY, 20,20).intersects(new Rectangle(playerX,550,100,8))){
                ballYdir=-ballYdir;
            }
            ballposX+=ballXdir;
            ballposY+=ballYdir;
            if(ballposX<0){
                ballXdir=-ballXdir;
            }
            if(ballposY<0){
                ballYdir=-ballYdir;
            }
            if(ballposY>570){
                ballYdir=-ballYdir;
            }
            if(ballposX>670){
                ballXdir=-ballXdir;
            }
        }
        repaint();

    }

}
```

Comment: From the code, it looks as though your ball movement is waiting on an ActionEvent to execute.  Hitting a key is an obvious ActionEvent, but I'm not sure what else that's getting done constitutes one.  That is, there is nothing going on that will cause the ball to move other than potentially timer expiration, mouse movement, clicks, (not sure if swing picks those up, but I assume so), etc.  In other words, some swing detected event needs to happen for the ball to move.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your exact code and it worked fine. There was no real lag or some better behavior while pressing a key. Hence there is a problem with you hardware maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice any lag but you were doing several things incorrectly which I have fixed.

- You should be overriding `paintComponent` and not `paint` for a `JPanel`
- You should invoke `super.paintComponent` as the first statement.  When you do that it will then set the background color for you and clear the screen each time.  It also does some other processing in the parent paintComponent method.
- I also set the size for the JPanel which made the yellow borders appear (although a little off on the right).  And the paddle was raised off the bottom edge a tad.
- I then packed the frame and centered it on the screen.
- I used `RenderingHints` via `Graphics2D` to smooth out the edges of the graphics.

All in all you did a pretty nice job.  I am not certain why you would be having a delay.  You might want to try increasing your x and y increment values and slowing down the timer.  But it worked fine for me as is.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Gameplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private boolean play = false;

    private int totalBrics = 21;

    private Timer timer;
    private int delay = 8;

    private int playerX = 310;

    private int ballposX = 120;
    private int ballposY = 350;
    private int ballXdir = -1;
    private int ballYdir = -2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame obj = new JFrame();
        Gameplay gamePlay = new Gameplay();
        gamePlay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,600));
        obj.setTitle("Breakout Ball");
        obj.setResizable(false);
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.add(gamePlay);

        gamePlay.setBackground(Color.black);
        obj.pack();
        // center on screen
        obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Gameplay() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        // borders
        g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 592);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 692, 3);
        g2d.fillRect(691, 0, 3, 592);

        // paddle
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        g2d.fillRect(playerX, 550, 100, 8);

        // ball
        g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g2d.fillOval(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20);

        g2d.dispose();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) {
        // timer.start();
        play = true;
        if (play) {
            if (new Rectangle(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20).intersects(
                    new Rectangle(playerX, 550, 100, 8))) {
                ballYdir = -ballYdir;
            }
            ballposX += ballXdir;
            ballposY += ballYdir;
            if (ballposX < 0) {
                ballXdir = -ballXdir;
            }
            if (ballposY < 0) {
                ballYdir = -ballYdir;
            }
            if (ballposY > 570) {
                ballYdir = -ballYdir;
            }
            if (ballposX > 670) {
                ballXdir = -ballXdir;
            }
        }
        repaint();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,
just found answer here:[Java window lagging on Ubuntu but not windows when code isn't lagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257540/java-window-lagging-on-ubuntu-but-not-windows-when-code-isnt-lagging)

Problem is with Linux's graphics scheduling, adding

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
```

after 
`repaint();`

caused, that everything works fluently now.

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue. But you are still not doing some things correctly.  You may want to check out my suggestions in my answer.